# Conditional function type

Tags: typescript, types

Given the following scenario,

```js
function doSomething({ id, name, onSelect, onUnselect }: TDoSomething) {
  if (onSelect) {
    // I want `onUnselect` to be defined here
    // ...
  }

  return { id, name }
} 

type TDoSomething =
  | IDoSomethingWithoutSelect
  | IDoSomethingWithSelect

interface IDoSomethingWithoutSelect {
  id: string
  name: string
}

interface IDoSomethingWithSelect {
  id: string
  name: string

  onSelect: (id: string) => void
  onUnselect: (id: string) => void
}
```

What I want to do is (conceptually?) simple: want to have `onUnselect` to necessarily be defined if `onSelect` is. In other words, if I pass `onSelect`, then this function must expect a `onUnselect` as well.

[(A playground to you can be accessed here.)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAFAN6IzIA0iYAhjrQmtgDbbTNgCqYAzu05REAXwBciACoARdFlwFiASkRkAUIkrBEJFkOiqNWrQHpTiAJKIA7vTAiABgj6CO0R4ihxEAI2wo2MCE2MiIeNgATtiaJuaIAHRJ6rFaLgIGUCRUyrGiKVrRUCCRSBRUtAw4YuqiiClQAJ4ADgGy8jj4hESIALyxAD5WchidSkQA6jD4cCBQrO5Qg8Mdit1T%20AvCKYRQUcD0EAGWIwpdxBt4s-OZarFUkvxQkd2xVdiPz6-56rv7h8dTmN1tM8FtoHctA9EE8XsQ3owPjCvvDYvpFpJsshPnCiKpegA%20RAANzgVDRvAyGN00Nh3XxRNJ5NEQA)

Turns out my attempts were failures. I don't know exactly what I should do to hit success.

[(This is something else I've tried to do)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAFAN6IzIA0iYAhjrQmtgDbbTNgCqYAzu05REAXwBciACoARdFlwFiASkRkAUIkrBEJFkOiqNWrQHpTiAJKIA7vTAiABgj6CO0R4ihxEAI2wo2MCE2MiIeNgATtiaJuaIAHRJ6rFaLgIGUCRUyrGiKVrRUCCRSBRUtAw4YuqiiClQAJ4ADgGy8jj4hESIALxWchidSj0AZLqxAD4DHYrdAOow+HAgUKzuUFMzQ3PEi-jrwuq56oRQUcD0EAGWgwpdxGqplMiS-FCR3c9V2G8fX899BsAPySbKvRDvT4qPoAPkQADc4FRAbwMiCwVQ-tCiKpevCkSj8qcHBcrjc7sMFks8Cs1pk1MSzmTrtt7iN9nhDtAnmkwNyoJiIVDuniCcjkLF0m5hELsaK4YiJbUgA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in` operator to narrow argument type to `IDoSomethingWithSelect`

```
function doSomething(arg: TDoSomething) {
  const { id, name } = arg;
  if ('onSelect' in arg) {
    arg.onUnselect(id);
  }

  return { id, name }
}
```

Comment: One side question, though.

When I call `doSomething({ onSelect: () => {} })` it doesn't require me to input `onUnselect`. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Your example should fail with compilation error `Argument of type '{ onSelect: () => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TDoSomething'.`